# android: how to using image in asset folder in html to load in webview

Tags: android, html, image, webview, assets

I have few image in asset folder! 
I want to use these image path for img tag in html! 
I use below code for get path but it doesn't work.

```
String p="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
```

what can I do?

this is my code

```
String p="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
String html = "<html  dir=\"rtl\" lang=\"fa-IR\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1\"></head><body class=\"rtl single single-post postid-38 single-format-standard custom-background\"></h3><center>MY TEXT<br><img  src="+p+" /><hr>FOOTER<hr></center></body></html>";
```

my problem is src=p , because this app can't load image!

Comment: just u think get bitmap from assest and load in imageview i u have html page than opne in webview

Comment: did u try `<img src="file:///android_asset/img.jpg"` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way its working for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String sHtmlTemplate = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"file:///android_asset/ic_launcher.png\"><p>Hello Webview.</p></body></html>";
    WebView wb = new WebView(this);

    wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
    setContentView(wb);


}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: have been error! force close! what can i do?

Comment: Hi @Gattsu, I am forced to define my src path as "/images/image.png", because html is dynamic in my case(coming from server). I have placed my image.png in images folder under assets but it s not showing up the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the same string to `src` attribute in `img` tag like :

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/img.jpg" ... >
```

If it is in a variable assing it as :

```
<img src="+filename+"... >
```

> I don't have a html file & i make html and load it from string at runtime

```
String filename ="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
String htmlString= "<html><img src="+ filename +" height='100%' width='100%'></html>"; // whatever is your html text
wb.loadUrl(htmlString);
```

[For more information, refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832100/2591002)

Comment: i wrote this code, but it doesn't work!!!

Comment: any error you got  ??

Comment: there isn't error! just don't load picture in my app

Comment: check in chrome -> Type in url chrome://inspect/#devices click inspect , then you can see in chrome console what is the error

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```
String p="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
String html = "<html  dir=\"rtl\" lang=\"fa-IR\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1\"></head><body class=\"rtl single single-post postid-38 single-format-standard custom-background\"></h3><center>MY TEXT<br><img  src="+p+" /><hr>FOOTER<hr></center></body></html>";
```

my problem is src=p , because this app can't load image!

Comment: remove it from answer

Comment: why can;t load image ?