# How to display HTML images along with the text in android.?

Tags: android, html, image, android-webview

I am new to android development.
I am using webview to display HTML pages in android, but only the text shows up.
Can you please help me with the problem.
thank you in advance, would be very helpful.

```
 WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    try{

        InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("Capacitor Code Calculator.html");
        int streamsize = stream.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[streamsize];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        String html = new String(buffer);
        view.loadData(html,"text/html", "utf-8");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Does it have to do something with "text/html" in   view.loadData(html,"text/html", "utf-8");

I have my html and image file both in assets folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing image in assets from HTML not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813646/referencing-image-in-assets-from-html-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you can't have spaces in your file name in the line:

```
InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("Capacitor Code Calculator.html");
```

What is the url you're giving in the `<img>` tag? Do you have spaces in this name also?

Comment: the HTML file opens correctly it show text as it is...but in case of images it gives a small square :(     And for the image URL i copied entire assets path of the file in assets folder

Comment: What is your url for your image look like?

Answer (score 0):

WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);

```
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

The last setWebViewClient() displays the images .....finally relieved :)
Hope it helps.